# Filter a Swift array with inner array details

Tags: ios, swift, filter

I have an array list of purchase details having a purchaseID , purchaseCategory . The purchaseCategory is another string array which details the products under that purchaseID. I am trying to filter , the main array list based on an item inside the purchaseCategory in swift. The following is the sample code

```
let purchaseList = [["purchaseId":1 ,"purchaseCategory" : ["meatballs" ,"burger","cheese" ,"onions" , "apples"]],["purchaseId":2 ,"purchaseCategory" : ["apple","orange" , "olive" , "cheese"]],["purchaseId":3,"purchaseCategory" : ["apple","orange" , "olive" , "cheese" , "Pepsi"]]]
```

How do we filter the purchaseList to return only details purchaseCategory having "olive"

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter`:

```
let purchaseList: [[String:AnyObject]] = [
    ["purchaseId":1 ,"purchaseCategory" : ["meatballs" ,"burger","cheese" ,"onions" , "apples"]],
    ["purchaseId":2 ,"purchaseCategory" : ["apple","orange" , "olive" , "cheese"]],
    ["purchaseId":3,"purchaseCategory" : ["apple","orange" , "olive" , "cheese" , "Pepsi"]]
]

func findCategoryContaining(word: String) -> [[String : AnyObject]] {
    return purchaseList.filter {
        if let arr = $0["purchaseCategory"] as? [String] {
            return arr.contains(word)
        }
        return false
    }
}

let result = findCategoryContaining("olive")
```

Result:

> [["purchaseId": 2, "purchaseCategory": (
>       apple,
>       orange,
>       olive,
>       cheese
>   )], ["purchaseId": 3, "purchaseCategory": (
>       apple,
>       orange,
>       olive,
>       cheese,
>       Pepsi
>   )]]

Comment: This converts all `String`s to `NSString`s, you can change `AnyObject` to `Any` to avoid that.

Comment: Can you have your thoughts on my answer

Answer (score 1):

So the other answers here involve casting the values of the inner dictionary to `String`. That would work fine, but maybe you should consider structuring your original data in a different way. You can keep the same information, but with type-safety, like this:

```
let purchaseList = [
  1 : ["meatballs", "burger", "cheese", "onions", "apples"],
  2 : ["apple", "orange", "olive", "cheese"],
  3 : ["apple", "orange", "olive", "cheese", "Pepsi"]
]
```

And you could filter it like this:

```
purchaseList.filter { (_,v) in v.contains("olive") }

// [
//   (2, ["apple", "orange", "olive", "cheese"]),
//   (3, ["apple", "orange", "olive", "cheese", "Pepsi"])
// ]
```

Comment: Can you have your thoughts on my answer

Answer (score 1):

Another way without explicit casting.

Assuming you have the `purchaseList` as `[NSDictionary]` or `[[String:AnyObject]]`:

```
let result = purchaseList.filter {
    $0["purchaseCategory"]?.containsObject?("olive") == true
}
```

If the `purchaseList` is `[AnyObject]`, you can:

```
let result = purchaseList.filter {
    $0["purchaseCategory"]??.containsObject?("olive") == true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because there aren't already enough answers (7!) *and* nobody mentioned an Array of Tuples and a Set yet, I'm going to give my input as well:

As [@oisdk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4892417/oisdk) already mentioned, you probably want a more type-safe way of doing this (Swift is all about type safety!). The way you wrote your array is in JSON style where everything is a String. Generally speaking, if you want to write top-notch Swift code, don't use `as`.

My initial suggestion would have been to use a tuple consisting of an integer and a set of strings. If you want to check the presence of something in a set, it's very fast (`O(1)`), an array can be much slower (`O(n)`). Of course this doesn't matter a whole lot if you only have very few items, but it's good practice to use sets if the order doesn't really matter. If you want arrays instead, you can just swap out `Set<String>` with `[String]`.

```
let purchaseList : [(purchaseId: Int, purchaseCategory: Set<String>)] = [
    (1, ["meatballs", "burger", "cheese", "onions", "apples"]),
    (2, ["apple" ,"orange", "olive", "cheese"]),
    (3, ["apple" ,"orange", "olive", "cheese", "Pepsi"])
]

let filtered = purchaseList.filter{ details in
    details.purchaseCategory.contains("olive")
}
```

**However** if you really want to have a good model, you need to get rid of those strings (the following only works if you don't intend to add categories at runtime). Strings can be really bad because they don't care if you make a typo, they can't know. For example: **Did you notice how you used the string `apples` in the first item, but `apple` in the second and third item?** That's exactly what happens when you use strings. To avoid this, you can use an `enum` with a certain categories already declared at compile-time:

```
enum Category {
    case Meatballs, Burger
    case Cheese, Onions, Pepsi
    case Apples, Orange, Olives
}


let purchaseList : [(purchaseId: Int, purchaseCategory: Set<Category>)] = [
    (1, [.Meatballs, .Burger, .Cheese, .Onions, .Apples]),
    (2, [.Apples, .Orange, .Olives, .Cheese]),
    (3, [.Apples, .Orange, .Olives, .Cheese, .Pepsi])
]

let filtered = purchaseList.filter{ details in
    details.purchaseCategory.contains(.Olives)
}
```

Of course you could also use a struct, which is basically a tuple with superpowers, to be more flexible and future proof.

EDIT: This works if you have to check for multiple categories:

```
enum Category {
    case Meatballs, Burger
    case Cheese, Onions, Pepsi
    case Apples, Orange, Olives
}

typealias PurchaseDetails = (purchaseId: Int, purchaseCategory: Set<Category>)

let purchaseList : [PurchaseDetails] = [
    (1, [.Meatballs, .Burger, .Cheese, .Onions, .Apples]),
    (2, [.Apples, .Orange, .Olives, .Cheese]),
    (3, [.Apples, .Orange, .Olives, .Cheese, .Pepsi])
]

func filter(includeCategories categories : Set<Category>) -> [PurchaseDetails] {
    return purchaseList.filter{ details in
        !details.purchaseCategory.intersect(categories).isEmpty
    }
}

filter(includeCategories: [.Pepsi, .Burger])
```

Comment: Can you have your thoughts on my answer

Answer (score 0):

The `filter` function can do that

```
let itemsContainingOlives = purchaseList.filter{ ($0["purchaseCategory"] as! [String]).contains("olive")}
```

Comment: this is actually not safe

Comment: I know but we can assume that any `purchaseId` has also an `purchaseCategory` array

Comment: It really depends on what you mean by "safe". Yes, this version will cause a crash if `"purchaseCategory"` isn't in the dictionary, or if it can't convert to `[String]`. But that's not necessarily a bad thing. Just returning `false` fails silently, and hides a possible error in your code.

Comment: Look at the first sentence of the original question, it says, it is safe... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
let purchaseList = [["purchaseId":1 ,"purchaseCategory" : ["meatballs" ,"burger","cheese" ,"onions" , "apples"]],["purchaseId":2 ,"purchaseCategory" : ["apple","orange" , "olive" , "cheese"]],["purchaseId":3,"purchaseCategory" : ["apple","orange" , "olive" , "cheese" , "Pepsi"]]]

let results = purchaseList.filter { (dictionary) -> Bool in
    if let category = dictionary["purchaseCategory"] as? [String]{
        return category.contains("olive")
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Safe** swifty way via filter:

```
purchaseList.filter { (element) -> Bool in
    return (element["purchaseCategory"] as? [String])?.contains("olive") ?? false
}
```

Answer (score -2):

check this code that helps to you!

```
var purchaseCategory  = NSMutableArray()
for item in purchaseList {
for (index, value) in item {
    if index as! String == "purchaseCategory" {
        if value.containsObject("olive") {
            purchaseCategory.addObject(value)
        }
    }
  }
}
// Output:
  [["apple","orange" , "olive" , "cheese"],["apple","orange" , "olive" , "cheese" , "Pepsi"]]
```

Answer (score -2):

Thanks all for the answer. All the answers were helpful . However , i too had a criteria to check with multiple category. I could not find the equivalent with Swift filters, so used the NSPredicates. Appreciate if any equivalents with Swift filters.

```
let purchaseList: [[String:AnyObject]] = [
["purchaseId":1 ,"purchaseCategory" : ["meatballs" ,"burger","cheese" ,"onions" , "apple"]],
["purchaseId":2 ,"purchaseCategory" : ["apple","orange" , "olive" , "cheese"]],
["purchaseId":3,"purchaseCategory" : ["apple","orange" , "olive" , "cheese" , "Pepsi"]]
]

var predicates = [NSPredicate]()
let categoryArray = ["olive", "Pepsi"]

for key in categoryArray {
var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "purchaseCategory contains %@", key as! String)
predicates.append(predicate)
}

var compundPredicate =  NSCompoundPredicate.orPredicateWithSubpredicates(predicates)
var filteredpurchaseList = (purchaseList as NSArray?)?.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(compundPredicate) as! [[String:AnyObject]]

Answer 

["purchaseId":2 ,"purchaseCategory" : ["apple","orange" , "olive" , "cheese"]],
["purchaseId":3,"purchaseCategory" : ["apple","orange" , "olive" , "cheese" , "Pepsi"]]
]
```

Comment: You asked me for my thoughts on your answer: It's horrible, unsafe, non-Swifty and super inefficient. Apparently you ignored everything I said in my answer (except the typo). I added code that works with multiple categories in my code

Comment: I don't think that this is a good option. Anything `NSPredicate` can do can also be done by `filter` - as `filter` can take a closure. There are of course places where using `NSPredicate` makes sense. This is not one of them. It really overcomplicates things.

Comment: The casting is also a real problem. It's slow, and unsafe. You're much better off sticking to normal Swift methods and functions. I do not understand why you're saying "I could not find the equivalent with Swift filters" - you've got several answers here, several of which do exactly what you were asking.